# WPF application depending on large file

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've got a quite simple WPF application, trying to implement a correct MVVM pattern.

The application in itself is simple: one listItem and one textbox + button for searching. On init, the entire content of a "large" (~50k to ~1million lines) file is loaded into the listItem. When the users enters text in textbox and clicks on the button, I go through the entire file and get the corresponding elements and refresh the listItem.

Right now, everything is fairly dirty, as you can see in the code below. I'm wondering how I can deal with this file. Should I keep everything in memory like I'm doing right now? Or should I reparse the file every time I need to? And how would all of this fit in MVVM pattern? I was thinking of a "Messages" class as a Model.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.LoadConversation();
    }

    private MessagesProcessor _messageProcessor = new MessagesProcessor("c.txt");

    private void LoadConversation()
    {
        foreach (var msg in _messageProcessor.Messages)
        {
            ListBoxConversation.Items.Add(msg.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void onSearchBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         var results = new List<Message>();
         results.AddRange(this._messageProcessor.GetSearchResults(word));
         foreach (var result in results.OrderBy(p => p.Date))
         {
                ListBoxConversation.Items.Add(result.ToString());
         }      
    }
}
```

**MessageProcessor.cs**

```
 public class MessagesProcessor
 {
    private List<Message> _messages;

    public List<Message> Messages
    {
        get
        {
            return _messages;
        }
    }

    public MessagesProcessor(string pathOfBaseFile)
    {
        this._messages = ParseBaseMessageFile(pathOfBaseFile); 
    }

    public IEnumerable<Message> GetSearchResults(string word)
    {
        return this._messages.Where(msg => msg.Content.Contains(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
 }
```

**Message.cs**

```
public class Message
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[" + this.Date.ToString("d") + " " + this.Date.ToString("t") + "]" + this.Author + " : " + this.Content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your code already working? You seem unsure.

Comment: @RubberDuck It's all working fine.

Comment: Have you tried the app with a large file? Are you only concerned with code style/approach or do you have additional performance concerns too?

Comment: @RobH Right now, I'm concerned with code style/approach. But after testing performances, 300000 lines seems to be the threshold. Average file should be around 100k-200k lines though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a nice example of how re-writing an application using MVVM can make life easier. It looks like you have the wrong idea about MVVM (your code should not be in the code behind). As a starting point, you would need an empty MVVM application with a main viewmodel and view, and know how to set up data binding and property changed events. If you haven't done this before, I would recommend taking a look at [MVVM light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) which is a small framework that can get you up and running quickly.

The idea is that your view and viewmodel should not care where the messages are coming from - that is not their concern. This is in line with [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and means that you can change how you read from the files (or read from somewhere else entirely) without touching any code in your V and VM layers. I would suggest starting with something like this:

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IMessageRepository _messageRepository;

    public MainViewModel(IMessageRepository messageRepository)
    {
        _messageRepository = messageRepository;
        FilteredMessages = _messageRepository.GetMessages();
    }

    // This will be bound to the search Button via a command
    public void FilterMessages(string searchString)
    {
        var messages = _messageRepository.GetMessages();
        FilteredMessages = messages.Where(m => m.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    }

    // This will need to be bound to the ListBox and raise PropertyChangedEvents when set
    public IEnumerable<Message> FilteredMessages { get; private set; }
}
```

**Model**

```
public interface IMessageRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Message> GetMessages();
}

public abstract class FileMessageRepository : IMessageRepository
{
    protected readonly string FilePath;

    protected FileMessageRepository(string filePath)
    {
        FilePath = filePath;
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<Message> GetMessages();

    protected Message BuildMessage(string line)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class LazyFileMessageRepository : FileMessageRepository
{
    public LazyFileMessageRepository(string filePath) : base(filePath)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Message> GetMessages()
    {
        // This will read from the file as it is enumerated
        return File.ReadLines(FilePath).Select(BuildMessage);
    }
}

public class EagerFileMessageRepository : FileMessageRepository
{
    private Message[] _cachedMessages;

    public EagerFileMessageRepository(string filePath) : base(filePath)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Message> GetMessages()
    {
        // This will read from the file once (slow) and keep the result in memory
        return _cachedMessages ?? (_cachedMessages = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).Select(BuildMessage).ToArray());
    }
}
```

With this implementation you are free to choose which `IMessageRepository` you use, and can carry out performance/profiling tests as required.